# Time validation with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to do time calculation based on user input. Before firing the calculation, I'm using momentjs to validate that the user time input. It seems to be acting strangely. For example, here is undefined input in browser console:

```
>moment(undefined).isValid()
>true
```

How do I use momentjs to validate user input?

Edit:

It seems that in strict mode you can validate everything else but dates with timezone abbreviations (EEST):

```
Tue May 05 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

The z parameter used for abbreviation is deprecated due to browser incompatibility: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restrict the pattern of the input date - you must use something like this:

```
checksDate = moment(date, ['DD-MMMM-YYYY', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'YYYY-MM-DD'], true);
```

Where this array:

```
['DD-MMMM-YYYY', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'YYYY-MM-DD']
```

is yours patterns.
The Third parameter in my moment statement define that moment.js must use strict mode. That means you can't use "." instead "-" in ISO format: "1990-09-01", for example. 
In Docs you can see this phrase:

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired
>   behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last
>   argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires
>   that the format and input match exactly.

In browser's console:

```
moment(undefined).isValid()
true
moment(undefined, [], true).isValid()
false
```

But its strong recommended to use pattern as i used in my example above.
Because without it moment.js  can do mistake for this dates:
`"01.11.2000"` and `"11.01.2000"` - it can be similar dates, then you use arbitrary user input.

read more: 
[moment.js Docs about validation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/)

I hope, it's clear.